# JS - Viewing a selected image in the browser

Tags: javascript

On a webpage, I display a users profile picture which they have assigned. Below this, I have a file input which allows a user to select a new profile picture. I want to display the new profile picture where the current profile picture is on the webpage.

For this, I need to change the src of the `<img>` tag that displays the users current profile picture. I need to change the `src` attribute of the `img` to whatever file the user selects when they want to change the profile picture.

I have put together some code, however it doesn't work at all.

Here is my **HTML**:

```
  // Profile picture I display in browser <img style="position: relative; left: 60px; top: 25px;" width="55px" src="{{ user.profilePic.url }}" alt="">

  <label id="profilePhoto_update" for="profilepic_update">Change Profile Photo</label>
```

**JS**:

```
img = $("#profilePhoto_update")

$("#profilePhoto_update").change(function(e) {
    for (var i = 0; i < e.originalEvent.srcElement.files.length; i++) {
        var file = e.originalEvent.srcElement.files[i];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function() {
               img.src = reader.result;
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        $("#profilePhoto_update").after(img);
      }
  });
```

Does anybody know how to implement this functionality? Thank you.

Comment: `$("#profilepic_update").change(function(e) {` - You're trying to bind it to the `label` instead of the input

Comment: @AlonEitan Ah ok, do you think you could write some code to implement the functionality I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're binding the event to the `<label>` instead of the `<input>`.

Also, I'd recommend using [Object URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) instead of Data URLs.

Here's a fixed example:

```
img = $("#profilePhotoImg")

$("#profilePhotoInput").change(function(e) {
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0])

    img.attr('src', url)
});
```

I hope this helps!